# File I/O with C++ open two files simultaneously

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

Isn't it possible to open two files simultaneously using different ofstreams? What I am trying to is writing to two ofstreams, one has a variable filename which changes every time the loop iterates, the other has a fixed filename and the data I am writing on is to be appended at every iteration of the loop. To demonstrate:

```
ofstream file_variable_name;
ofstream file_to_be_appended;

{  //THIS IS A LOOP, variable_name changes at every iteration

file_variable_name.open(variable_name.c_str(), ios::out);
file_to_be_appended.open("fixed name", ios::out | ios::app);

//Do lots of things here, make data ready to be written to file

file_variable_name << "write something" << endl;
file_to_be_appended << "write same as above, but this is to be appended" << endl;

file_variable_name.close();
file_to_be_appended.close();
}
```

Somehow, I could not even manage to get the second file to be created let alone opened and appended. I can send the full code (it's around 1000 lines or so, needs be truncated), as well, but I thought the above would explain what I am trying to do, and any logic flaws would be apparent to pros.

Thanks in advance for all suggestions!

Comment: Why you try to open file_to_be_appended in loop? Why not open it outside of loop and use it?

Comment: There's nothing that would prevent opening two files simultaneously (so long as they're different files).  Must be something else going on.

Comment: It would help if you could narrow down your original program to a **short**, **complete** sample program, and if you could paste that program in its entirety into your question. See http://sscce.org/. for more information.

Comment: @ForEveR I took the file_to_be_appended out of the loop (I was thinking of opening and closing it everytime), but nothing changes.

Comment: You should check the boolean value of `file_variable_name` immediately after the open. If it is `false`, then the file did not open correctly. Also, you might print the value of `variable_name` in each loop to be sure that it the name is correct.

Comment: @Robᵩ the files with the variable names are created, opened and written perfectly. I end up with 300+ different files which I need. The thing is I also need a single big file where all these files are combined into one. I thought I could do it using the `ios::app` to append it in the loop, so that file would get bigger and bigger at each iteration. However, I cannot get that file even created. I agree it is hard for you guys to help me (which I appreciate) without a working example, so I am trying to shorten my code to a suitable length to post here.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was opposite. I'm curious - what is the **precise** name of the file you are trying to create? And, what OS are you using?

Comment: @Robᵩ the line is `cstrainFile.open("girder1_midspan_cstrain.txt", ios::out | ios::app);`. I am on Win7, using NetBeans 7.1.2 with g++.

Comment: Have you tried the code you posted (with a few extra lines so that it will compile)? Because it seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it far harder than it is. Generally there's no need to use .open() and .close() methods, and you don't need to keep reopening the same file:

```
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::ofstream file_to_be_appended("fixed name");

    char const *list[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
    for (auto s : list) { // My compiler doesn't have generalized initializer lists yet
        std::ofstream file_variable_name(s);

        file_variable_name << "write something\n";
        file_to_be_appended << "write same as above, but this is to be appended\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would turn the code you posted into a simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  ofstream file_variable_name;
  ofstream file_to_be_appended;

  file_variable_name.open("variable_name.txt", ios::out);
  file_to_be_appended.open("fixed_name.txt", ios::out | ios::app);

  file_variable_name << "write something" << endl;
  file_to_be_appended << "write same as above, but this is to be appended" << endl;

  file_variable_name.close();
  file_to_be_appended.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Now edit it and add a loop with some dummy file names. If you encounter any problems along the way, this code is simple enough to help narrow down what the issue might be.